# .NET MAUI change fontsize in textcells

Tags: xaml, maui

So I recently started my first project with .net maui and everything was looking good until I tried styling my App and making it look better. I have this really simple ListView with a List of persons binded to it. Inside the listview is a textcell that binds to the name of the persons. Now I am trying to change the fontsize of the text inside the textcell and I can't figure out how as there is no fontsize attribute.

Thats the code I have:

```
    <ListView x:Name="Persons"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.Row="1"
        ItemSelected="Persons_ItemSelected" 
        Margin="10,10,10,0"
        RowHeight="40"
        BackgroundColor="LightGray"
        >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}"></TextCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

I have tried to google the problem and haven't got any results.

Answer (score 1):

From document [TextCell Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.textcell?view=net-maui-7.0), we could find that `TextCell` doesn't have `FontSize` property.

But you can use [Label](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/label) to achieve this, which has `FontSize` property.

Please refer to the following code:

```
   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HasUnevenRows="True"> 
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                     <!-- use Label instead  -->
                    <Label  Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Caption"/>
                </ViewCell>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```